# I am trying to get google-services.json file from google, however i am not able to enable google sign in

Tags: android, json, android-studio, sha1, google-signin

I am trying to enable google sign in and generate a google-services.json file from this page, however i always get the following message.

[image]

I have created a 0auth 2.0 client id in my developer console but how do i tell google this? No fields seem to be working, every time i click on Manage Auth Clients it takes me to console page.
This is the last thing i need to do for my help so any help would be appreciated. Thank you.